# What is the difference between ffmpeg packages and sources

Tags: ffmpeg

I found two things for installing ffmpeg at www.ffmpeg.org/download.html
There are packages and sources(snapshot)
What is the snapshot?
And what is the difference between them?
All of things are different, among ffmpeg-3.0.1 and packages and snapshot??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have many options on the [FFmpeg Download](https://ffmpeg.org/download.html) page.

---

## Source code

You can download the code from any **release branch** or from the **git master branch**.

### Release branch

The releases are for distributors and those who want to avoid backward incompatible API changes. Some bugfixes are backported in point releases, but new features, and anything that will cause a major API change will not.

The big, green button at the top of the page links to the source code of the most current release version.

### git master branch

This is always the most current code available, and will always have more features than any release branch. General users are encouraged to use the git master branch as it is probably stable 99% of the time or more.

You can get the git master branch source code by either:

- **Using `git`** as shown under the "Get the Sources" section on the download page. This will [clone](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-clone) the master branch including all of the associated git history which is useful for development, finding bugs and regressions, etc.
- **Downloading the snapshot**. This is generated once daily from git master and does not include any git stuff, so **it is a much smaller file**.
- **Downloading the git snapshot**. This is generated once daily from git master and does include the extra git stuff. Useful for users behind a firewall or who are otherwise unable to use `git`.

---

## Packages

These are links to various packages or binaries for a variety of platforms as an alternative to compiling the source code. Some are generated daily from git master, and some are really outdated. These are provided by volunteers and third-parties.

Comment: Got it. It is so helpful to me. Thank you so much.