# How to run ffmpeg - no exe or bat file

Tags: ffmpeg

I downloaded ffmpeg 3.1.1 but there is no .exe or .bat file to run from the command line.  I searched for answers.  Apparently, there should be a \bin folder.  I end up with a lot of folders but no such folder and no executable file.  All ffmpeg files have a .c extension or other extensions but nothing that can be run from the command line.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You downloaded the source code, but you probably expected an executable file. FFmpeg only provides the source code, but some third-party volunteers do provide executables:

- Windows - [Zeranoe FFmpeg builds](https://ffmpeg.zeranoe.com/builds/)
- Linux - [Relaxed FFmpeg builds](https://johnvansickle.com/ffmpeg/)
- macOS - [Evermeet FFmpeg builds](https://evermeet.cx/ffmpeg/) & [Zeranoe FFmpeg builds](https://ffmpeg.zeranoe.com/builds/)

Also see [What is the difference between ffmpeg packages and sources?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/36903542/1109017)

Comment: I only got this answer on stackoverflow.